# Load a different view controller based on previous view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a navigation controller with 3 view controllers inside of it.

A. Categories Controller
B. List (dynamically generated from web)
C. Detail View Controller

The flow of the app is click a category, then a list item and then view detail about that item. The problem I'm having is that each time I load the List controller it retains the table I loaded dynamically. This is fine when I hit Back on the Detail controller, but very bad when I hit a different category.

How can I check to see which view controller is pushing onto my controller? So I can know if I should check for a category and reload content or if I should display what was previously loaded before the user went to the Detail Controller?

Comment: Are you using Storyboards?

Comment: Yes I am using storyboards

Comment: Alright, I can't help then. Unsure how to test properties and load dynamically, I'm betting it's possible, just haven't used storyboards beyond one test app. Good luck.

Comment: I ended up writing a method in controller B that unloaded the view controller whenever a button in Controller A was clicked. Worked like a charm. Kind of a hack though

Answer (score 0):

You can check which view controller pushed the current view controller with the vc's [presentingViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController) property

Comment: Or you could pass the necessary category information into your view controller B (even though its content doesn't depend upon it) when it's initialized--add a custom init method. Then use that information stored in B when creating view controller C.